# I can't stop java SwingWorker process

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker, tcpserver

I was running a tcp server in java which is done using SwingWorker class. First time it will start successful but when i stop and start the process it won't work. i couldn't find what is the bug please help me to fix this

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SwingWorkerDemo extends JFrame {
     /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
        private static Socket clientSocket;
        private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
        private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        private static String message;

    public SwingWorkerDemo() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
        final JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
        final LongRunProcess process = new LongRunProcess();



        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                try {
                    process.execute();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                startButton.setEnabled(false);
                stopButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

        stopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello There");

process.cancel(true);
startButton.setEnabled(true);
stopButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });


        this.getContentPane().add(startButton);
        this.getContentPane().add(stopButton);

        this.pack();
        this.setSize(new Dimension(300, 80));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new SwingWorkerDemo().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    class LongRunProcess extends SwingWorker {
        /**
         * @throws Exception
         */
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4545);  //Server socket

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4545");
            }

            System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 4545");

            while (true) {
                try {

                    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();   //accept the client connection
                    inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); //get the client message
                    message = bufferedReader.readLine();
     if(message.equals("shutdown")){

    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = runtime.exec("shutdown -s -t 00");
    System.exit(0);

     }
     else if(message.equals("restart")){
    Runtime runtime1 = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc2 = runtime1.exec("shutdown -r -t 00");
    System.exit(0);


     }

                    System.out.println(message);
                    inputStreamReader.close();
                    clientSocket.close();

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
                }
            }

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any trace of an attempt to close the server socket.

Comment: How do i stop it from the UI-Thread ?

Comment: Have you already tried calling `.close()`?

Comment: You mean Longrunprocess.close(); ?

Comment: That's up to your code. If you want to put it in a method and name that method `close`, there's nothing stopping you.

Comment: But how do i close that particular socket from the UI-Thread?

Comment: By calling `.close` on it.

Comment: wrong decision to accept Thread instead of reading official Oracle tutorial, did you search for isCanceled(), check for CancellationException too, btw both answers here aren't correct

Comment: @mKorbel OP doesn't really need the SwingWorker since he's not modelling a task which takes some time and then *completes, updating the GUI*. He only wants a background task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this. In this i have made some changes also

```
public class Test extends JFrame {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket clientSocket;
    private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private static String message;

    public Test() {
        initialize();
    }

    LongRunProcess process;

    private void initialize() {
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
        final JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop");

        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                try {
                    process = new LongRunProcess();
                    process.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                startButton.setEnabled(false);
                stopButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

        stopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello There");

                process.closeServer();

                startButton.setEnabled(true);
                stopButton.setEnabled(false);
                process.stop();
            }
        });

        this.getContentPane().add(startButton);
        this.getContentPane().add(stopButton);

        this.pack();
        this.setSize(new Dimension(300, 80));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    class LongRunProcess extends Thread {
        /**
         * @throws Exception
         */
        public void closeServer() {
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Closed Now");
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4545); // Server socket

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4545");
            }

            System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 4545");

            while (!(serverSocket.isClosed())) {
                try {

                    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // accept the client
                                                            // connection
                    inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                            clientSocket.getInputStream());
                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); // get
                                                                            // the
                                                                            // client
                                                                            // message
                    message = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    if (message.equals("shutdown")) {

                        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                        Process proc = runtime.exec("shutdown -s -t 00");
                        System.exit(0);

                    } else if (message.equals("restart")) {
                        Runtime runtime1 = Runtime.getRuntime();
                        Process proc2 = runtime1.exec("shutdown -r -t 00");
                        System.exit(0);

                    }

                    System.out.println(message);
                    inputStreamReader.close();
                    clientSocket.close();

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As per the Javadocs of [SwingWorker#execute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#execute%28%29)

> Note: SwingWorker is only designed to be executed once. Executing a
>   SwingWorker more than once will not result in invoking the
>   doInBackground method twice.

Hence the behavior you are seeing. So in order to achieve what you are looking. you need to create new Instance of `LongRunProcess` every time you push start button. Something like this.

declare at class level

```
LongRunProcess process = null;
```

modify action listener

```
 startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            try {
                process = new LongRunProcess();
                process.execute();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            startButton.setEnabled(false);
            stopButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not trying to execute it in a serial manner i just want start-stop procedure so usually only one swingworker is running at a time

Comment: Yeah but you are creating LongRunProcess instance only once in intialize method, so you are trying to re-use same instance again and again. you must create a new instance of LongRunProcess after you push start button.

Comment: But how do i stop the current running process also with closing opened port otherwise it will throw an exception  port is in use